# Erro Unity "Animator"

Tags: unity3d, animação

Eu estava fazendo um jogo e apareceu este problema:

Asset 'PlayerAC': Transition in state 'AnyState' doesn't have an Exit Time or any condition, transition will be ignored

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1):

Você precisa criar uma condição para ele mudar de estado para a animação de Death.

Ou seja, você um tempo fixo `has exit time` no inspector ou você deve `criar um parâmetro` e configurar ele para essa transição, pode ser um `booleano` ou um `trigger`. Acredito que o botão de criar parâmetro esta coberto pelo teu console nesta screenshoot.

Aqui tem um vídeo sobre configurar animações do player https://youtu.be/fotMn6x7aoU